# TYPO3: Use t3lib_TCEforms in frontend plugin

Tags: forms, typo3

I would like to use as much standard TYPO3 as possible to create a form to edit single records from tx_mytable.

In pi1 i load the tca for the table:
t3lib_div::loadTCA('tx_mytable');

Now I would like to use standard functions to create my form elements more or less like it is done in the backend...

I found this for the front end but cannot find any working examples:
t3lib_TCEforms_fe.php (that extends the normal t3lib_TCEforms)

Is this the right way to go or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I got something working but not really that nice code in the frontend

Here is a link that telss that TCA is not enough but two new entries in the array is needed
http://www.martin-helmich.de/?p=15

It is itemFormElName and itemFormElValue

```
// include tceforms_fe (place outside class where pipase is included)
require_once(PATH_t3lib.'class.t3lib_tceforms_fe.php');

// load TCA for table in frontend
t3lib_div::loadTCA('tx_ogcrmdb_tasks');

// init tceforms
$this->tceforms = t3lib_div::makeInstance("t3lib_TCEforms_FE");
$this->tceforms->initDefaultBEMode(); // is needed ??
$this->tceforms->backPath = $GLOBALS['BACK_PATH']; // is empty... may not be needed

//////////REPEAT FOR EACH INPUT FIELD/////////
// start create input fields, here just a single select for responsible

// conf used for tceforms similar to but not exactly like normal TCA
$conftest = array(
    'itemFormElName' => $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_ogcrmdb_tasks']['columns']['responsible']['label'],
    'itemFormElValue' => 1,
    'fieldConf' => array(
        'config' => $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_ogcrmdb_tasks']['columns']['responsible']['config']
    )
);

// create input field
$this->content .= $this->tceforms->getSingleField_SW('','',array(),$conftest);

// wrap in form
$output = '<form action="" name="editform" method="post">';
$output .= $this->content;
$output .= '</form>';

// wrap and return output
return $output;
```

Still looking for a working example with custem template for input fields.